# What is the options parameter of spark_write_csv dplyr function?

Tags: r, apache-spark, amazon-s3, dplyr, sparklyr

I was looking for a way to make `spark_write_csv` to upload only a single file to S3 because I want to save the regression result on S3. I was wondering if `options` has some parameter which defines number of partitions. I could not find it anywhere in the documentation. Or is there any other efficient way to upload resultant table to S3?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`options` argument is equivalent [`options`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@options(options:java.util.Map[String,String]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter[T]) call on the `DataFrameWriter` (you can check [`DataFrameWriter.csv` documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@csv(path:String):Unit) for a full list of options specific to CSV source) and it cannot be used to control the number of the output partitions.

While in general **it is not recommended**, you can use Spark API to coalesce data and convert it back to `sparklyr` `tbl`:

```
df %>% 
  spark_dataframe() %>% 
  invoke("coalesce", 1L) %>% 
  invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", "_coalesced")

tbl(sc, "_coalesced") %>% spark_write_csv(...)
```

or, in the recent versions, `sparklyr::sdf_coalesce`

```
df %>% sparklyr::sdf_coalesce()
```